# C++ : prim() in an "if statement"

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement

While studying *the C++ programming language* by B. Stroustrup, it has been mentioned the existence of the prim() functions which reduces the scope of the declared variable to one single block.

This is an example provided by the book:

> ```
> if (double d = prim(true)) {
>         left /= d;      break;  
> }
> ```

Despite understanding its interest, I cannot figure out how to use it: is it part of a certain library ? Of must I precise the standard because Visual Studio isn't able to recognise the function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"is it part of a certain library ?"_ Not that I know of. Probably refers to an example given in a former section, or just a general example how function calls should or shouldn't be used. Give us a bit more of context from the citation please.

Comment: If [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/dc.c) is the code you're referencing, then it looks like its purpose is to parse that non-terminal in the grammar. My guess is that the book is saying you can reduce the scope of `d` by declaring it in the `if`, and that `prim` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ew, bool parameters :P

Comment: Ok. It is a user defined function. Thank you @chris

Comment: The function does not limit the scope of the variable. It's a simple user defined function that returns a `double`. It's return value is however declared in the if statement, which both create the variable and checks it's value. Also, as you mentioned, it's scope is limited to the if, but this is only due to where it's declared.

Comment: @Wyllich I have to agree with some now deleted comment. Bjarne had chosen a horrible example for a `prim()` testing function (I read _test for prime number_) there. The parameter/return type combination should be just vice versa, but then the `d` variable definition to show is just useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code demonstrates an ability to declare a local variable inside a header of an `if` statement. It has nothing to do with `prim(...)` function, which is probably defined in some other place in the book.

Here is another example:

```
int k = 3;
if (int d = k*50) {
    cout << "hello " << d << endl;
}
```

This [prints](https://ideone.com/2luXyd) `hello 150`. Variable `d` is accessible only inside the body of the `if` statement.

Note that the scope of `d` extends to `else` branch as well ([demo](https://ideone.com/9WX8EG)):

```
int k = 0;
if (int d = k*50) {
    cout << "hello " << d << endl;
} else {
    cout << "goodbye " << d << endl;
}
```

**Note:** In the example above there is no reason to check `d` in the `else` branch because it is guaranteed to be zero.

Comment: Relevant reading: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no `prim()` function in the standard library. It is a user defined function used to demonstrate that the condition in the [if statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) can be a declaration. The function itself is defined in **Section 10.2.1** on page no. **245**.